# Stop the JPA (Hibernate) Criteria API creating repeated INs for a group of OR Predicates

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I'm using the Criteria API with the Hibernate implementation of JPA.  I want to improve the structure of my generated SQL query so that the same IN expression isn't repeated for each OR predicate.

I want to do this because the code is running on GAE and I get a StackOverflowError in the case where the list of names is long in the IN condition (It's due to Hibernate using StringBuilder to build the parameter list).  I've pinned the problem down to this section of code as when I remove, say 8, of the OR predicates the code runs without error.  The code runs fine on non-memory restrictive environments (my PC)....and yes I have increased the instance memory allocation on GAE but I still get the same error.

The Java code I have to build this part of the query is below (parameter names edited and I'm using @StaticMetamodel classes for the parameter names):-

```
private void buildNamesToQuery(List<String> names, Root<ARoot> theRoot,
        Join<Entity1, Entity2> aJoin, List<Predicate> orPredicates) {

    orPredicates.add(aJoin.get(Entity1_.name1).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(aJoin.get(Entity1_.name2).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(aJoin.get(Entity1_.name3).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(aJoin.get(Entity1_.name4).in(names));

    orPredicates.add(theRoot.get(Entity2_.name5).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(theRoot.get(Entity2_.name6).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(theRoot.get(Entity2_.name7).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(theRoot.get(Entity2_.name8).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(theRoot.get(Entity2_.name9).in(names));
    orPredicates.add(theRoot.get(Entity2_.name10).in(names));
}
```

This generates SQL with the following structure (parameter names edited):-

> ```
> select 
>      //lots of detail for the select
>   where
>     //lots of condition detail
>     //but what I'm interested in is below
>   and (
>     Entity_.name1 in (?,?,?....
>     ) //Lots of names
>     or Entity_.name2 in (?,?,?....
>     ) //same list of names
>     or Entity_.name3 in (?,?,?...
>     ) //same list of names again
>   //.
>   //continues like this for remainder of the query
>   //
> );
> ```

How can I change the Criteria API code so the SQL becomes this?:-

> ```
> and (
>    joinEntity_.name1 or joinEntity.name2 or joinEntity.name3 ... etc IN (?,?,?...)
> ```

with the same long list of names?  Hopefully that's clear enough for you to suggest a solution.

Comment: That sounds like a HORRIBLE DB design which is propagating out into a horrible JPA experience.

Comment: Is your desired SQL valid at all?

Comment: Desired SQL seems to work

Comment: `joinEntity_.name1 or joinEntity.name2 or joinEntity.name3 IN (?,?,?)` is a valid syntax? In which database?

Comment: In a database where `name1` and `name2` are booleans ;-)